# As of 2017 is it still possible to get a transaction confirmed without a fee?

Tags: transaction-fees, transaction-selection

In the past it was possible to get a transaction without a fee confirmed if the inputs and outputs had a high enough [priority](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_fees#Priority_transactions) and followed [some rules](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_fees#Historic_rules_for_free_transactions). As of 2017 is a "free" transaction still possible if you don't care about how fast it will be confirmed? Several hours or even a day or two would be acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bitcoin consensus rules do not require transactions to have a fee, so it's still theoretically possible for a free transaction to be confirm.

It is, however, unlikely that any miners today will confirm free transactions.  You can test this by sending yourself a free transaction to see if it confirms (but be sure you use a quality wallet, such as Bitcoin Core, that has features for handling transactions that never confirm).

Comment: For the record: I created a free transaction that got confirmed in about an hour (maybe lucky?). The transaction was within the rules mentioned in the question.

Comment: @tlo: how did you resolved/avoided the "error code: -26;error message: 66: insufficient priority"?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. It is possible. But what exactly do you want to achive? Either you want to minimize the fees or you want to delay transaction confirmation. Difference in details...